# on updating props in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

There's a number of posts in SO related to not being able to update props in ReactJS. E.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26089532/274677).

In the referenced post the explanation is given that this is part of the ReactJS philosophy, helps in debugging, etc. Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34210024/274677) (in the same thread) shows how it's done inside ReactJS (by using `Object.freeze`).

I am ReactJS newbie and so put together this small example to try to see what happens when one attempts to modify props (also in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3eo4necy/))

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id='react-app'></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/react/0.14.0-rc1/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/react/0.14.0-rc1/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
     var rce = React.createElement.bind(React);
     var TodoList = React.createClass({
       propTypes: {
         todos: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.string).isRequired,
       },
       render: function() {
         var props = this.props; 
         var todos = this.props.todos;
         var self  = this;
         return rce('div', {}
                   ,rce('ul', {}
                      , (function(){
                        return todos.map(function(x, i) {
                          return rce('li', {key: i}, x);
                        });})())
             ,rce('button', {onClick: function() {
               // delete props.todos;         // fails
               // props.todos = [];           // fails
               todos.splice(0, todos.length); // succeeds
               console.log(todos);
               self.forceUpdate();
             }}, 'clear all'));
       }
     });
       var todoList = rce(TodoList, {todos: ['walk dog', 'feed cat', 'water flowers']});
       ReactDOM.render(todoList, document.getElementById('react-app'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am sure the above code violates many good practices but it's apparently easy to modify `props`. I understand this is because `Object.freeze` is called on the `props` object and not on its properties as well and so as it is, it does not "freeze" against splicing (or changing a props' object's attribute values). My questions are:

1. how should the above code be written to respect ReactJS philosophy?
2. if not modifying props is such a core tenet of ReactJS's philosophy why isn't it enforced more strictly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `react` philosophy, you are advised not to edit the props because it is not how `react` is design ([Thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html)).

You should use the `state` of your view which conforms to changes and you may pass some data from `state` to `props`.

see the correct example of your code:

```
var TodoList = React.createClass({
   propTypes: {
     todos: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.string).isRequired,
     onSomeAction: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
   },


   render: function() {
     var todos = this.props.todos;
     var self  = this;
     return rce('div', {}
               ,rce('ul', {}
                  , (function(){
                    return todos.map(function(x, i) {
                      return rce('li', {key: i}, x);
                    });})())
         ,rce('button', {onClick: this.props.onSomeAction});
   }
 });
```

The logic of what to do and how, when the button is clicked, should be place in the view's owner, unless you manage you own state in the current view.

Also,
There is a concept which defines *dummy* views and *smart* views.
in short, dummy views are such that they only get properties and shows some data on screen, but they do not interact with other objects or able to change the view's `state`. 
However, smart views are such that they are interacts with others, responding to events and etc. as well as able to change their state and pass any other data to its children.

Hope its clearer for you now...