# Child Components are not being re-rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, components

I'm new to React. As a learning exercise I'm building an chess application

I want to change the DOM of child based on state in parent. Currently there is no change in child components on change of state in parent.

Parent Component

```
class Game extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            game :{ 
                board_position = { 'One' : ''}
            }
        }

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(){
        let p = this.state.game.board_position;

        // some computations on p
        p = { board_position : { 'One' : Math.random() } }

        this.setState({
            game : p
        })

        //this.forceUpdate(); // Just trying different methods to make it work
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e) }>
                <Piece {...this.state.game.board_position} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Child Component

```
Class Piece extends Component{

    constructor(){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            clr : ''
        }
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        let c;

        // some computations that change value of c based on props
        if( typeof ( this.props.game.one) == number ){
            c = 'Red'
        } else {
            c = 'Blue'
        }


        this.setState({
            clr : c
        })

    }

    render(){
        return(
            <span>{this.state.clr}</span>
        )
    }
}
```

On call of handle click method, there is a change in state of the game. However, subsequent changes in Child are not seen.

Can anyone please help me out? Where am I going wrong?

I'm not sure how to implement ref as suggested [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892672/react-why-child-component-doesnt-update-when-prop-changes). However, I don't think that is a good solution. Probably I'm having some conceptual misunderstanding.

PS: Please ignore any syntax error. This code is a strip down of real code.
If you want to take a look at full code - [go over here](https://github.com/sidoknowia/chess)

Comment: There are so many weird things going on here. You shouldn't be force-updating. Setting state should care of that for you. Also, never mutate state directly. You've misspelled `constructor` and don't have braces around `this.state.clr`.  You're not using the props you pass from the parent, and `componentWillMount` runs once... thus no change occurs after first render

Comment: Hi,
As I said, Please ignore syntax errors. This is strip down version of code and not the real code itself.
I've also given the link to real code

Comment: It's your job to provide a [mcve]. No one will comb through your code for you. Isolate the problem yourself and provide a *complete* example without syntax errors.

Comment: you're not using the props that are being passed by the parent component

Comment: I'm using prop to make some calculation. Value of variable C will depend on value of props. But not using props directly

Comment: Your code block has syntax issues it is better to post a code with minimum errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`componentWillMount` in your `Piece` component will only fire once.

Are you updating your state each time the props change as well ? For example using `componentWillReceiveProps`

Also you could just display the props directly in your render function

```
render(){
    return(
        <span>{use the props directly here}</span>
    )
}
```

Try to avoid using state whenever possible, and stick with just rendering your component based on props.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I cannot use props directly, Since I need to make some calculations and use the calculated value

Comment: You need to do the calculations each time the props change don't you ? Anyways, don't do the calculations in your component, do them in a Higher Order component or a state management system but only use your React components to display data. React is a view engine not a calculation engine.

Comment: I understand. But those calculations will determine what is to be rendered in output

Comment: Do the calculations in your render method and don't save anything in the state of `Piece`

Answer (score 0):

it's a pretty basic react process:

```
class Game extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            game :{ 
                 board_position = { 'One' : ''}
             }
        }

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(e){
        let p = this.state.game.board_position;

        // some computations on p
        p = { board_position : { 'One' : Math.random() } }

        this.setState({
            game : p
        })
    }

    render(){
        return(
        <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <Piece board_position={this.state.game.board_position} />
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Child: //can be a function instead of a class

```
const Piece = ({board_position}) =>{
  const {board_position} = this.props;
  let clt = board_position;
  //do some stuff

  return(
    <span>{board_position}</span>
  );
};
```

if you want to do more calculations you can use componentWillReceiveProps(newProps)

Answer (score 0):

A component re render when it's **props** or **states** get changed. There will be certain life cycle methods get invoked based on the values of **props** and **own states**.

**The way you accessed your **props** is wrong.** 
It should be

```
this.props.One
```

Life cycle method you should have used is **componentWillReciveProps(nextProps)**. In that case you should access the relevant prop like below

```
nextProps.One
```

I have created a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uxfvfay9/1/) (your code had errors if you fixed those and looked at your log you could have easily figure out where the error is)

Comment: componentWillMount will only be called once, so the game won't change when the o game prop changes.

Comment: sorry. Constructor is called once. componentWillMount will be called every time the component is going to update. But yes I used the wrong life cycle method. It should be componentWillReceiveProps. And I have updated my answer now.