# React with Hooks: When do re-renders happen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When will a React component using hooks re-render?

Let's assume the component:

- Manages state with `useState`
- Receives `props` from its parent

Will a re-render happen directly *after* the following events, and *only* at those points in time?

- Component receives new `props`
- `state` is updated

**Related Question**

Let's assume the component has several `useState` expressions and a user interaction causes multiple states to update.

Will the component re-render multiple times, once per `state` value that changed, or will it batch these related changes into one single re-render?

Comment: `react devtools` is good to answer your question you just check the highlight option and see if your component is rending multiple times or not

Comment: State updates and prop updates will cause the component to re-render. Multiple synchronous state updates will be batched together into one re-render

Comment: @Tholle i agree, hope that answer your question

Comment: @G.aziz can you explain how to find it using react devtools please

Comment: @BuddhikaW it's checkbox that you can find in options

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A component will re-render in the following cases considering it doesn't implement shouldComponentUpdate for class component, or is using React.memo for function

- Component receives new props
- state is updated
- Context value is updated(if the component listenes to context change using useContext)
- Parent component re-renders due to any of the above reasons

> Let's assume the component has several useState expressions and a user
>   interaction causes multiple states to update.
>
> Will the component re-render multiple times, once per state value that
>   changed, or will it batch these related changes into one single
>   re-render?

`useState` doesn't merge the updated values with previous ones but performs batching like `setState` and hence if multiple state updates are done together, one render take place.

Comment: Thanks! What does multiple states updated together mean?

Comment: What I meant is that if you have two state variables `countA` and `countB` and you update both of them one after other using their respective state setters, they are batched

Comment: Sorry to dig in, but do you mean within one tick of the JS event loop? I.e. in what case would they *not* be batched?

Comment: There is a small time interval within which if multiple calls to useState setter occur their updates will be batched. However if setter calls occur with a mininum time interval greated than the batching interval then those updates will not be batched

Comment: "Component receives new props" shouldn't be in this list. It doesn't rerender per se. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38893045/3032209

Answer (score 5):

Found [this nice article](https://blog.bitsrc.io/exploring-react-renders-different-ways-a-component-gets-re-rendered-edc11403b754) on this topic. I'll add the summary in case someone needs a quick read.

### What causes a render in react?

**State modification**

Component re-renders when its state is manipulated, simple as that. So, when you modify the state of your component it tends to re-renders with the new state value.

**Passing Props**

If the parent component has triggered a rerender all the child component will rerender too, generally you would only want the specific child components to rerender only if the component is consuming some props or the passed props are modified but that isn’t the case, it does not matter if the props are consumed, modified or not, the child components will re-render if the parent component has triggered a render.

**Using the Context API**

When modifying the state which is also the value passed to the context, the whole child components tree would get rerendered. Again doesn’t matter if the child component is consuming the context data or not, it will still rerender. The rerenders depend on the value passed to the provider but still, all the whole components tree would get rerendered.

**Passing down references**

In case of an object, array and, function comparison is based on references i.e. the exact memory location so, their comparison even though they seem equal yields false, in React Object.is method is used to compare the different values.

Example:

```
{}==={}             //false
[]===[]             //false
{a: 5}==={a: 5}     //false
[1,2,3]===[1,2,3]   //false
```

(when comparing the previous state to the new state, it returns false because they do not have the same reference. Only the value is the same)