# what could be the case that parrent re-render but its child won't?

Tags: reactjs

I was told that children do not re-render if the props of their parent change but if the parent's STATE changes.

In the case below, when I click on the button, Child re-render, which makes sense as its parent's state was triggered, but I don't know why Grandchild get re-render as well!! its parent's state (Child's state) didn't change.

So, what is the rule here?

**What would be the case:**

**1) the App renders but none of the Child and Grandchild render?**

**2) the App renders but only Child renders not Grandchild?**

**BY THE WAY, I don't mean how to use Memo or pureComponent, I just want to know how React renders the nested children :)**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div style={{ padding: "50px" }}>
      <button onClick={() => setText(text + 1)}>add</button>
      {text}
      <Child />
    </div>
  );
};

const Child = () => {
  console.log("child");
  return (
    <div>
      <Grandchild />
    </div>
  );
};

const Grandchild = () => {
  console.log("Grandchild");
  return <div>:))</div>;
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a brief - SFC (Stateless Functional Component) does always re-render if it's parent re-renders.

Changing the state in your `App` component causes `Child` to re-render. The same with `Grandchild`, since it's parent (`Child`) has re-rendered.

**However**, if you would transform `Child` into a class and use `React.PureComponent`, it would not re-render since no prop was passed in (no prop nor state was changed). `Grandchild` wouldn't re-render neither.

`PureComponent` does a shallow prop comparison, which would avoid excessive re-renders.

By the way -  *"I was told that children do not re-render if the props of their parent change but if the parent's STATE changes."* - that's not true. Even if state of the parent component changes, re-render of children can be avoided.