# this.props.firstCard returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react.js and I'm trying to math.random a number and put it in this.props.firstCard property, but it returns undefined. I tried some variables but only result is undefined or syntax error. Code:

```
handleClick() {
let firstCard = this.state.isFirstCardChosen;
function chooseCard() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (80 - 1) + 1);
}
if (firstCard == false) {
  this.props.firstCard = chooseCard;
  console.log(this.props.firstCard);
}
}
```

What's wrong with this one? Thanks in advance.

Comment: sry there's a `this.props.firstCard == chooseCard;` instead of 'this.props.firstCard = chooseCard;', which returns 'not extensible' error.

Comment: this.props is immutable. You cannot modify it. Go through some react tutorials on setState and props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to hazard a guess and suggest that

***if:***

the problem isn't just one caused by the fact you are trying to mutate props ([props are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26089687)).

***and:***

You're using ES2015 class syntax

***then***

the problem *may* be that your `handleClick` method **isn't properly bound to the component state** so the call to `this.props` returns `undefined`.

To solve this you can bind the `handleClick` in the constructor as follows:

```
constructor (props){
  super(props);
  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: what syntax should i use then? es2016?

Comment: Difficult to tell, can you post up the code where you use _handleClick_?

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else has said the props is immutable. Also make sure you are setting props correctly and binding your handleClick function in your constructor i.e:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    his.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}
```