# Render after componentWillReceiveProps and before componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here's my problem:

I'm new at reactjs and I'm trying to make this app using SWAPI (swapi.co). For now I need to list characters and some info about them. The problem is I have this component called `SelectedCharacter` that returns some info about a character that was selected in a div.

The moment a character is passed through props to this component, I get a response via xmlhttp and the info is displayed. The thing is that I want to put a `"Loading..."` message while the data is fetched. This is how I was trying to figure it out:

I set up the `componentWillReceiveProps` function, where I test if I'll need to load stuff and the `componentDidUpdate`, where I fetch the data from this api and update the status.

I know, from react life cycle, that a render is called between `componentWillReceiveProps` and `componentDidUpdate`, and it indeed is.

I expected, then, that if I did this:

```
render() {
  if (criteria) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }
}
```

The thing is: even if this criteria is true (I tested it using `console.log()`), the message doesn't show until the next re-render. Am I doing anything too wrong here? If it helps, my code is at [github.com/piubellofelipe/StarWars](https://github.com/piubellofelipe/StarWars), the problem is at the selected_characters.js, in the src paste.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking at your code, trying to work this out for you and I don't have any concrete answers for you, but I've noticed a few things that may be making things a bit unpredictable.

---

#### 1. Calling `forceUpdate`

```
componentWillReceiveProps(){
    this.setState({loading:true})
    this.forceUpdate();
}
```

Calling `setState` will trigger a render, so the call the `forceUpdate` is not required here.  This means there are more renders occurring than you might expect.

I believe this may be the cause of your issue for a pretty complicated reason.  From the [`setState` docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> ... `setState()` is also asynchronous, and multiple calls during the same cycle may be batched together.

And from the [`forceUpdate` docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate)

> Calling `forceUpdate()` will cause render() to be called on the component...

My theory is that the call render triggered by `setState`, asynchronously setting `loading` to `true`, is being delayed and the one from `forceUpdate` is sneaking in first, while `loading` is still false.

#### 2. Updating `props`

```
this.props.selected.moviesList = moviesListNames;
```

Components should never, *ever*, update their own `props`.  Usually, this would be stored in `state` instead.

For more details on this, read [this section of the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26089687/6902543).

#### 3. Importing axios, but not using it

```
import axios from 'axios'
```

This one isn't really an issue (other than an unused import), and might just be preparation for where you're heading.  axios gives a much nicer developer experience than `XMLHttpRequest` (in my opinion) for http requests and will clean up the `fetchData` function a lot, which will make troubleshooting easier.

---

I hope this helps a bit, and you're enjoying React.  Feel free to follow up on any of these points in the comments or as new questions.

Comment: Thank you, I'll fix these things before continuing.