# Handling rendering async data when using redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am confused a little bit about the idea of re-rendering.

- **First question:** In `React` **without** `redux` do changing in components `props` trigger re-render ?
- **Second question:** How to handle async data when using redux,  in `react without redux` after `AJAX` request i used to put `setState` inside `componentDidMount()` so changing in `state` causes component to re-render. Using redux i read that the only way you must use `connect` helper in order to make component re-render is that true?
- **Third question:** In the following code (Component that returns `navbar` with child elements that depends whether the user is authenticated or not) I triggered unexpected behavior sometimes the `navbar` returns `Loading...` and stops forever. Other times it returns `Loading...` at first then automatically changed to `User Profile` if user logged in or `Sign Up` if not. why is that happening?
- **Fourth question:** When using `redux` where should i put async data and make component waits these data before re-render?

  ```
   class Header extends Component{

      renderComponent(){

       switch(this.props.auth){

       case null : return <li>Loading...</li>;
       case false: return <li><a>Log In</a></li>;
       default:    return <li><a>User Profile<a/></li>
      }
     }

   render(){
     return(

      <nav>
          <ul>
            {this.renderComponent()}
          </ul>
      </nav>

       )
     }
   }

   const mapStateToProps = ({auth}) => {
     return {
       auth
     }
   }

   export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header);
  ```

**Action Creator**

```
export const fetchUser = ()=>{

    return async (dispatch) => {
      const res = await axios.get('/api/currentuser');

       dispatch({
         type: FETCH_USER,
         payload: res.data
       });
    }
};
```

**Reducer**

```
export default (state = null, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'FETCH_USER': return action.payload || false;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Thank you, Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: for managing async data you should use a library like redux-saga.

Answer (score 0):

**First Question** - No, changing props won't rerender - [Why can't I update props in react.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089532/why-cant-i-update-props-in-react-js)

**Second Question** - Yes, you have to use the connect helper and use middlewares(redux-thunk, redux-saga), which can be used for async calls . Their documentation has all the details - https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk & https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga

**Third Question** - We will need to see more code to answer. Need to know how "auth" is set.

**Fourth Question** - You should use a middleware as explained in the second question. The middleware will take care of getting the data and re-rendering.

**Code**

Note: Add a mapDispatchToProps and call the function in your compponentDidMount().
Your reducer and action creators look correct. Just one observation in your reducer explained below:

```
 import * as actions from '<action creator file path>';

    class Header extends Component{

          componentDidMount() {
              this.props.fetchUser();
            }
        renderComponent(){

         switch(this.props.auth){

         case null : return <li>Loading...</li>;
         case false: return <li><a>Log In</a></li>;
         default:    return <li><a>User Profile<a/></li>
        }
       }

     render(){
       return(

        <nav>
            <ul>
              {this.renderComponent()}
            </ul>
        </nav>

         )
       }
     }

     const mapStateToProps = ({auth}) => {
       return {
         auth
       }
     }

const mapDispatchToprops = (dispatch) => {
return {
   fetchUser = () => dispatch(actions.fetchUser())
}
}
     export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Header);
```

**Reducer**

```
  const initialState = {
    payload:null,
...<other states>

}

        export default (state = null, action) => {
      switch(action.type){
        case 'FETCH_USER': return {...state,payload:action.payload}|| false;
        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
```

This is just the basic outline and you should be able to take it from here.

Comment: I updated the code with reducer and action creator, and please could you clarify your answer on the fourth question what middlewares for example?

Comment: @Dodz, i have updated my answer with the code.  Please check and let me know for any queries

Comment: Its a header component that is used in every page, which means i will reach a point that `fetchUser()` is called multiple times. if a component also rely on `fetchUser()` for example `Profile` component . So it will be called twice one from profile and other from header, would it be okay ?

Comment: You can have a parent component for header,profile and other components. something like a <Layout /> . All the other components would be the child of this component and call the fetchUser() in <Layout />. Then it wont be called multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

**4**
In the redux store. If there is any change to the data in the redux store. All mounted components that listen to the store will rerender.

I've used Redux Thunk for async code: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk. It allows you to return promises in your action creators.

So the data flow works something like this: Redux store is initialized with empty values. This causes the page to render the first time. Then you have async calls to your backend to fetch the data. As the redux store is populated with the data it causes the site to rerender.