# Remove specific array element, not just last one with .pop - Redux-form

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux-form

https://codesandbox.io/s/qzm5q6xvx4

I've created the above codesandbox. I am using redux-form ([https://redux-form.com]) that where you can add and remove fields to populate the form using `.push` and `.pop` [2](https://redux-form.com).

The problem with using .pop it only takes off the last array element, I would like the option for each .push created element to have its own "remove" button, therefore not simply taking the last item off the array.

I assume I would need to assign the `.pop` to look at the matching react `.map` element somehow?

```
const renderForm = ({ fields, label }) => (
  <div>
    <div
      variant="fab"
      color="primary"
      className="jr-fab-btn"
      aria-label="add"
      onClick={() => fields.push()}
    >
      ADD
    </div>
    <div
      variant="fab"
      color="primary"
      className="jr-fab-btn"
      aria-label="add"
      onClick={() => fields.pop()}
    >
      REMOVE
    </div>
    {fields.map((newIntel, index) => {
      console.log("newIntel", newIntel, index);
      return (
        <Field
          name={newIntel}
          key={index}
          label={label}
          placeholder={label}
          component={renderTextField}
          placeholder={label}
          label={label}
        />
      );
    })}
  </div>
);
```

Any ideas would be welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Yes thanks, this helps but cant get it into button format on each element.

Comment: You really shouldn't be modifying `props` from within the component receiving them (e.g. changing what `fields` contains inside `renderForm`). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089532/why-cant-i-update-props-in-react-js) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will look into the `fields` which is a prop to your renderForm, it contains a method `remove` to remove a specific element. Just pass it the index.
below is modified code-block of your component. I have made it class-component:

```
class renderForm extends React.Component {
 render(){
  let {fields, label} = this.props;
  const removeName = (index) => {
    fields = fields.remove(index);
  }
return(
  <div>
    <div
      variant="fab"
      color="primary"
      className="jr-fab-btn"
      aria-label="add"
      onClick={() => fields.push()}
    >
      ADD
</div>

    {fields.map((newIntel, index) => {
      console.log("newIntel", newIntel, index);
      return (
        <div>
          <Field
            name={newIntel}
            key={index}
            label={label}
            placeholder={label}
            component={renderTextField}
          />
          <p
            variant="fab"
            color="primary"
            style={{'cursor': 'pointer'}}
            className="jr-fab-btn"
            aria-label="add"
            onClick={() => removeName(index)}
          >
            REMOVE
      </p>
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>
 )
}}
```

Hope, you can understand the code-block easily. Just paste the above code in place of your renderForm component. It will work like magic. :p

Comment: Yep, this is great. I was moving towards this implementation. Thanks