# TS RadioGroup returns type string on change handler rather than array of possible strings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui

I have an interface defined as so:

```
export interface StopData {
    stopName: string,
    stopType: 'stop' | 'waypoint'
}
```

I have a radio group for selecting the 'stopType', with two radio buttons.
One with the value 'stop' and one with 'waypoint'.

My onChange handler in the radio group looks like so: `onChange={event => stopData['stopType'] = event.target.value}`
However I've got a TS error:
*Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"stop" | "waypoint"'*

So even though I only have two radio buttons that match the strings my interface defines, the radiogroup still considers the type of event.target.value to be "*any*" rather than "*'stop' | 'waypoint'*"

**How do I update *stopData[stopType]* without changing my interface to accept *stopType: string*.** (Bonus if I can wrap them both updaters into the same change handler)

FYI: I'm using React, TS and MaterialUI for my tech stack.

The whole (relevant) code is as follows:

```
export default function CreateTripStop(stopData: StopData) {
    return (
        <Box className={classes.flexContainer}>
            <TextField label='Stop Name' placeholder='Cupola Hut' name='stopName'
                onChange={event => stopData['stopName'] = event.target.value} />
            <RadioGroup row name='stopType' defaultValue="stop"
                onChange={event => stopData['stopType'] = event.target.value}>
                <FormControlLabel
                    value="stop"
                    label="Stop"
                    control={<Radio color="primary" />}
                    labelPlacement="start"
                />
                <FormControlLabel
                    value="waypoint"
                    label="Waypoint"
                    control={<Radio color="primary" />}
                    labelPlacement="end"
                />
            </RadioGroup>
        </Box>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update like this:

```
onChange={event => stopData['stopType'] = event.target.value as StopData["stopType"]}
```

Comment: Your onChange() functions are trying to change a Prop passed to your component. You are not supposed to do that. That's why we use State. You can change State not Props.

Comment: Each 'trip stop' is maintained in a 'stop list' which is a state in the parent element, this component will simply be reused for every stop.

Comment: Then you should pass an event handler down to the child and handle the change in the parent.  `onChange={event => changeHandler(event.target.value)} />`, handle the change in the parent. With your current code, you won't get the radio button changes back in the parent component.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking that since if I modified an element of a parent's array from the child, the changes would be maintained, is that not the case?

Comment: You may check this link and see the 2nd answer. I can't explain the whole thing in a comment.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089532/why-cant-i-update-props-in-react-js